# find value of column base on other column condition

Tags: pandas

I would like to find a value of column A base on column B's condition. for example, find the ts of first 'B' from value columns:

```
import pandas as pd

data = [[10,"A"],[20,"A"],[30,"B"],[40,"B"]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['ts','value'])
print(df)

:    ts value
: 0  10     A
: 1  20     A
: 2  30     B
: 3  40     B
```

I would like to print out 30 for this example!

Comment: `df.loc[df['value'].eq('B'), 'ts'].iloc[0]`. If it throws an error, then you don't have any `B` in `value`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that with slice

```
df.loc[df['value'].eq('B'),'ts'].iloc[0]
Out[163]: 30
```